# Binary to Decimal Conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal

I have created a function to convert ascii to decimal:

```
function asciiToDecimal(text) {
    var decimal = "";

    for (var i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        decimal += text[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(10) + " ";
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

and now I want to convert binary to decimal directly. I have tried to convert to ascii and then decimal but that is not always possible. I have seen a couple of other SO Q&A that present a function, but the answer is usually not the the desired output (see below).

**Input:**

```
01101101 01111001 00100000 01101110 01100001 01101101 01100101 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01101010 01101001 01101101 00111111
```

**Desired Output:**

```
109 121 32 110 97 109 101 32 105 115 32 106 105 109 63
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the parseInt with base2 option.

`parseInt(string, radix);`

```js
document.write(parseInt('01101101', 2))
```

And with this, you'd take your input string, split it on spaces, and parse the binary numbers individually.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt